# Unable to get active classes length without timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to get active classes length based on clicking. If i use timeout then only am getting the exact count. how can i achieve without using timeout to get exact active classes length.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 
 <style>
  a {
   text-decoration:none;
  }
  .active {
   color:orange;
  }
 </style>
 
</head>
<body ng-app="sample">

<div ng-controller="test">
<div data-ng-init="names=[{name:'XML'},{name:'Java'},{name:'Tutorial'}]">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="myObject in names"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-model="toggle" ng-class="toggle ? 'active' : ''" ng-click="toggle=!toggle; getActiveLength();">{{myObject.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module('sample',[]).controller('test', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.getActiveLength = function() {
   $timeout(function(){
    var total = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".active")).length;
    console.log("Length " + total);
   
   },500)
  }

 })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly suggest me for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of things which happen when you click on anchor tag:

1. `toggle` value is changed
2. `getActiveLength()` is called

When `getActiveLength()` is called, though the value of `toggle` is changed it won't reflect on DOM since angular [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) process is not completed. So you need to check for active elements post digest process using `$scope.$$postDigest`.

```js
angular.module('sample',[]).controller('test', function($scope){
  $scope.getActiveLength = function(myObject) {
    $scope.$$postDigest(function () {
      var total = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".active")).length;
      console.log("Length " + total);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="test">
  <div data-ng-init="names=[{name:'XML'},{name:'Java'},{name:'Tutorial'}]">
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="myObject in names">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="toggle ? 'active' : ''" ng-click="toggle=!toggle; getActiveLength();">{{myObject.name}}
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Sorry its' not working with angularJs version. I want to use version 1.6.1 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: @vadlamani I have update script to `1.6.1` and it seems to be working fine. Share your code in order to help you out better!

Comment: In 1.6.1 version while we clicking on first selection element it's showing length as 0. Please check once.